# How to put the extracted image at the right place for Apache Tika EPub Parser used in Android

Tags: android, apache-tika

I have ported Apache Tika to Android. I have a basic question. While working on EPubParser, I am able to get the URI of the images in the EPub book. I have got the Text of the EPub book using BodyContentHandler and the image links using LinkContentHandler.

Now my problem is how can I show these images at the same place where they were in the source. Can anyone give me a pointer in this regard?

This is my code...

```
   InputStream myInputFileStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.flashback);

    BodyContentHandler bodyHandler = new BodyContentHandler();

    LinkContentHandler linkHandler = new LinkContentHandler();

    TeeContentHandler handler = new TeeContentHandler(bodyHandler, linkHandler);

    EpubParser ePubParser = new EpubParser();

    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    try{

        ePubParser.parse(myInputFileStream, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());

    }

    catch(SAXException e){

    }
    catch(TikaException e){

    }

    catch(IOException e){

    }

    String plainText = bodyHandler.toString();

    List<Link> linkLists = linkHandler.getLinks();
```

Comment: Why are you not using a ContentHandler that returns XHTML, and looking in that for where the img tags appear?

Comment: i have used the following code. but it seems not to be working. it is giving blank output. what do you suggest? <code>BodyContentHandler bodyHandler = new BodyContentHandler(500000);
  Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
  
        XHTMLContentHandler testHandler = new XHTMLContentHandler(bodyHandler, metadata);</code>

Comment: hi Gagravarr, thank you for the answer. could you please show me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to change how you're doing it. Instead of getting the text and the links independently, get them all at the same time. To do this, fetch the text contents from Tika as XHTML rather than text, with something like:

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)
             SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
    TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
    handler.setResult(new StreamResult(sw));

    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());

    String xhtml = sw.toString();
```

Once you have the XHTML, look through for links and images. When you find those, you'll know exactly where things go in relation to the surrounding text.

Comment: thank you Gagravarr for your suggestion... i have done the same way as you have suggested...